Limit properties question on illegal manipulation
I couldn’t find any information on whether this is a property or it just happened to work in my case when solving a problem.
Let’s say I have a limit
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\bigg( 1+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^{x}$$
Am I then allowed to make the following manipulation?
$$\bigg(1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x}$$

To compute $\lim_{x\to a}$  you begin by replacing $x$ by $ a$ as you did, BUT YOU have to know the indeterminate forms.

Surely not. That would make your expression equal to one since the limits would be independent, but that’s not the case. There is a property of a limit, though, which could seem a tad similar. Namely, if  you have a mapping $\phi=g \circ f$ where $g$ is continuous, and you want to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \phi(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(f(x))$, you are allowed to move the limit inside the continuous function:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \phi(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x))
$$

No, this isn't it. $$\lim_{x→0} f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x→0} f(x)^{\lim_{x→0} g(x)}$$

$1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form

@EgorLarionov thank you for your answer, could you write it down as an actual answer on the site so I can accept it?

@ТymaGaidash, I don’t see the problem if it’s an actual $1$.

Surely not. That would make your expression different since the limits would be independent, but that’s not the case.
There is a property of a limit, though, which could seem a tad similar. Namely, if you have a mapping $ϕ=g\circ f$ where $g$ is continuous, and you want to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \phi(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f(x))$, you are allowed to move the limit inside the continuous function:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \phi(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f(x))=g(\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x))
$$
